# Financial actions and two click confirmation - two buttons vs checkbox+button

Tags: confirmation, actions

I'm trying to decide how to display a confirmation for some super important actions. The two options I'm trying to pick from are:

1. After clicking the first confirmation button, it'll be replaced by another one and the text above it would be replaced. This is what I currently have implemented, see below.
2. Using a combination of a checkbox and a button, where the button is disabled until you check the checkbox.

Other suggestions are welcome too.

The actions in question are money-related (or, more specifically, Bitcoin-related). One is a confirmation that you have a copy of the keys (without that, the user would lose access to his funds), and the second is a confirmation of sending a transaction. Both actions are inside a dialog window.

To illustrate, here are pictures of the transaction confirmation, where I implemented a two button confirmation:

[image: confirm transaction - step 1]

[image: confirm transaction - step 1]

And here's the confirmation for keeping a safe copy, where I haven't implemented two-click confirmation yet:

[image: confirm saving private keys]

So, why do you think is the most effective way of ensuring the user read the text and understood the action he's committing?

Also, if you have any other advice for making those dialogs better, I would love to hear it.

Thanks!

Comment: I have to warn that you may be heading down catastrophe lane - what if as the user reads the last dialog ('OK, I have a safe copy'), there's a power-cut and their machine switches off? What if I'm on a laptop and as I read this my wife shouts hysterically from the kitchen and when I'm back I discover my 5 year old daughter pressed the button? Have you considered forgiveness?

Comment: @Izhaki that dialog is displayed prior to depositing any funds, after the very first step. At this stage, there's no money at stake yet. He can just re-start the process if that happens. But also, I cannot offer forgiveness in the way this works - the sensitive data that needs to be saved is never shared with the server, so its 100% up to the user to handle it properly.

Answer (score 4):

If you go with a two-click confirmation process, you should ensure the design can't be tripped by a double-click. Worse would be if in the design a double-click could result in either a confirm-confirm or a confirm-cancel, depending on which end of the button they double-click.

One way would of course be the second approach you mentioned, that of "using a combination of a checkbox and a button, where the button is disabled until you check the checkbox". Another way would be to have the second button appear in addition to the first, like this:

[image: cancel/confirm added to bottom of the dialog, below "Yes, authorized"]

---

Here is another example from Twitter, where the "mark all read" button requires a confirmation. Note how the confirmation button does not overlap the original action button, while a double-click results in a safe no-op.

[image]